# SubSonic SqlQuery, get count of records on paged query

Tags: subsonic

I have a large table that must join to multiple Tables, 
I have a query with several conditions that user may fill some of them.
I used paged method of SqlQuery.
Now, how can I get total record count? I want to implement paging on gridview and don't know how many records my query will return?

Comment: I used getrecoudcount before Paged method and get response. but if there is better solutions while this make problem on larg count, please inform me

Answer (score 0):

Paged should return a PageList which has TotalPages and TotalRecords properties on it.

Comment: thanks, but Paged return a SQLQuery and that doesnt have PageList.
I used Version 2.2